# Two functions which agree on all integrals differ only on a null set

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I have two functions which agree on all integrals for a measure space. It seems intuitive that they should differ only on a null set but I am having trouble finding a formal proof...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A = \{x \mid f(x)>g(x)\}$  Then $A$ is measurable and $\int_A (f-g)(x)\mathrm{d}x = 0$, so $\mu(A)=0$.  Similarly for $B = \{x \mid f(x)<g(x)\}$.

Comment: Why is that set measurable?

Comment: @bottledcaps The difference of two measurable function is measurable, so $A$ is the inverse image of $(0,\infty)$ under a measurable function.